# JDateChooser set number of displayed Entrys in Month Combobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jdatechooser

Well i must admit i am a little ashamed that i can not find a solution for my newest problem because it sounds so basic and simple.

In JDateChooser there is a JCombobox which enables the user to select a month.
obviously it has 12 entrys. This Combobox displays only 9 entrys at the same time, to reach the other three months you have to scroll up and down.

Is there any way to do this without scrolling, i.e. enlarge the popup vertically?

Comment: are you using any IDE?

Comment: @ArpitPorwal yes i do, (eclipse Mars)

Comment: use the code written in the answer. first(350) is width and another is height. this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Will Help

```
dateChooserCombo1.setCalendarPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 220));
```